# Set row height of a TTTableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I know that question has been asked many times (for example : [How to resize TTTableSubtitleItemCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450639/how-to-resize-tttablesubtitleitemcell)), but I never found a simple answer to it : is there simple way to set the row height of a TTTableView ?
I really need to do this and I can't find any way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];
self.tableView.rowHeight = 80;}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

or override this method:

```
+(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView rowHeightForObject:(id) object
{
    return 106;
}
```